# Using a Samba SIM with a Dell laptop

Tags: wireless-networking, mobile-broadband, sim

I'm looking at the following item:

https://www.sambamobile.com/Signup/SelectDevice

I have a Dell Latitude D630 which has a SIM card port near the battery section. Would I be able to use the SIM in the link with the laptop? I don't want to get the dongle + SIM unless I have to. Would I need extra software to use this SIM?

Comment: The D630 has the connector for a SIM below the battery section. However that is just the connector. You need to install additional hardware to actually use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work with your Dell Latitude D630 as long as your mobile broadband card is not locked to any U.S. carrier (e.g. AT&T.)

Also, as far as I know, you don't need any additional software to use the Samba Free Service. You will need to install Firefox, because Internet Explorer is not supported at the moment.

FAQ: http://help.sambamobile.com/FAQ